# Can I identify and learn the properties of a magic item that I can't attune to without using the identify spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, attunement

If I have an item I *can't* attune to, (e.g. a Dwarvern Thrower for a non dwarf or a robe of the Archmagi if I'm not a Spellcaster): can I still find out what it is after a short rest?

I am not asking how to identify it, I'm asking if the fact I can't attune to it prevents me from identifying it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### A short rest will suffice.

The rules for [using a magic item](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/magic-items#UsingaMagicItem) state:

> At the end of the rest, the character *learns the item’s properties, as well as how to use them.*

After a short rest with the item, you learn its properties and how to use it. The particular attunement requirements are "properties" of the item. There are no class based restrictions on learning via short rest what an item's properties are.